# Is it possible to write files to your machine (local drive) using GitLab CI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a Python script, using GitLab CI, which will create a Pandas dataframe and write this as a .csv file on my machine.

As a test script I've created the following ***do_stuff_2.py*** file:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f'Hello.\nCurrent date/time is:{current_time}')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)

df.to_csv('C:\\<USER_PATH>\\Desktop\\df_out.csv', index = False)
```

This should:

- print the current time
- generate a dataframe with 10 rows and 4 columns which is randomly populated with values between 0 and 100
- print said dataframe
- save the dataframe to the local drive

When the CI pipeline is executed I get no errors and the first 3 steps run successfully:
[image: Pipeline execution screenshot]

I have a ***.gitlab-ci.yml*** file with the following:

```
stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    image: python:3.6
    script: 
        - echo "Running python..."
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - python do_stuff_2.py
```

and a ***requirements.txt*** file:

```
numpy
pandas
```

It looks like I've got everything set up correctly, as the time is being displayed and the `print` function returns the dataframe. However, no file is written to the specified location. When I run the script locally everything works as expected and the dataframe is saved on my desktop as ***df_out.csv***.

I'm using Python 3.6, on a Windows 10 machine.

Is there an alternate way to do this from within a CI pipeline in GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [install](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html) the gitlab-runner on your local machine.

If you can't, you can use `artifact:` keyword to upload the result of your script on the gitlab server and download it afterward from the UI. Your `gitlab-ci.yml` will look like :

```
stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    image: python:3.6
    script: 
        - echo "Running python..."
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - python do_stuff_2.py
    artifacts: 
        paths:
        - df_out.csv
```

and you code must change to :

```
df.to_csv('df_out.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: I can't seem to install a runner - might be to do with business access rights. I've registered the runner and it appears in the UI on GitLab but when I try to install I get an access denied error. With your above code the `artifact` keyword will cause the CSV file to be saved but I would still have to download it manually after the CI pipeline has finished running, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to dowload it manually but you can also use the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive) to download it

Comment: GitLab is throwing an error for the .yml configuration above: "This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: (<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 8 column 9"

Comment: Thanks, that worked. That answers my original question, but do you know if it is possible to use the API whilst the pipeline is still running to download the newly created artifacts? Looking at the API documentation you linked to, something along the lines of: `- 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/42/artifacts?job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"'` makes sense. Would I include that line in the .yml file?

Comment: You can but in another job than which is produce the artifact. But why do you want to do that ? As you will execute this command in the context of the runner, the artifact will be downloaded on the runner filesystem (to which you don't have access if I understand well)

Comment: I thought that was the case when reading the docs. And you're right, I can't use the runner on my local machine. Using the CI/CD UI to download manually is sufficient - was just asking if it was possible/easy to set up (seems like it is more hassle than it is worth).